# Routing firefox docker container traffic through wireguard container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers. One of them runs wireguard and the other runs firefox on port 5800.
I want to have access through WAN to firefox Web GUI (port 5800). However, All outbound traffics from firefox container should be routed through wireguard container.

So I wrote this docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/New_York
    volumes:
      - ./wg-server:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped
  firefox:
    image: jlesage/firefox
    ports:
      - "5800:5800"
    network_mode: "service:wireguard"
    volumes:
      - "./firefox:/config:rw"
```

Here is wg0.conf in wireguard container:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
Address = 10.0.1.2/32
MTU = 1420

[Peer]
PublicKey = BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB==
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = ENDPOINT_IP:PORT
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

But it's not working:

```
Creating wireguard ... done
Creating wg-network_firefox_1 ... error

ERROR: for wg-network_firefox_1  Cannot create container for service firefox: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode

ERROR: for firefox  Cannot create container for service firefox: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

There is no logs for firefox container btw.

Actually, I tried to route firefox traffic by modifying the routing table to route traffic. However, I couldn't access to firefox web gui afterwards. I prefer a solution using docker networks rather than modifying routing table.

Answer (score 0):

The error is: "conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode".

You can't publish ports on a container if you've configured it to run in the network namespace of another container. You would need to configure the port publishing on the `wireguard` container:

```
services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/New_York
    volumes:
      - ./wg-server:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5800:5800"
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped
  firefox:
    image: jlesage/firefox
    network_mode: "service:wireguard"
    volumes:
      - "./firefox:/config:rw"
```

Comment: I did that but I cant connect to firefox web GUI from WAN.